# Write rows to BigQuery via nodejs BigQuery Storage Write API

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems quite new, but just hoping someone here has been able to use nodejs to write directly to BigQuery storage using [@google-cloud/bigquery-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage).

There is an explanation of how the overall backend API works and how to write a collection of rows atomically using [BigQuery Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#pending) but no such documentation for nodejs yet. A [recent release 2.7.0](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#270-2021-09-27) documents the addition of said feature but there is no documentation, and the code is not easily understood.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage/issues/222) requesting an example but thought I'd try my luck to see if anyone has been able to use this API yet.

Comment: As a separate channel you can also file a feature request via [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), impacting more users it can be an indicator for developers to extend the documentation pages supplying intuitive examples for Bigquery Storage Write API NodeJS client library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have a BigQuery table called **student** with three columns **id**,**name** and **age**. Following steps will get you to load data into the table with nodejs storage write api.

Define student.proto file as follows

```
syntax = "proto2";
message Student {
    required int64 id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    optional int64 age = 3;
}
```

Run the following at the command prompt

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. student.proto
```

It should generate **student_pb.js** file in the current directory.

Write the following js code in the current directory and run it

```js
    const {BigQueryWriteClient} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery-storage').v1;
    const st = require('./student_pb.js')
    const type = require('@google-cloud/bigquery-storage').protos.google.protobuf.FieldDescriptorProto.Type
    const mode = require('@google-cloud/bigquery-storage').protos.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.WriteStream.Type

    const storageClient = new BigQueryWriteClient();
    
    const parent = `projects/${project}/datasets/${dataset}/tables/student`
    var writeStream = {type: mode.PENDING}
    
    var student = new st.Student()
        
    var protoDescriptor = {} 
    protoDescriptor.name = 'student'
    protoDescriptor.field = [{'name':'id','number':1,'type':type.TYPE_INT64},{'name':'name','number':2,'type':type.TYPE_STRING},{'name':'age','number':3,'type':type.TYPE_INT64}]
    
    async function run() {
        
        try {
        
            var request = {
              parent,
              writeStream
            }
            var response = await storageClient.createWriteStream(request);
        
            writeStream = response[0].name
            
            var serializedRows = []
    
            //Row 1
            student.setId(1)
            student.setName('st1')
            student.setAge(15)
    
            serializedRows.push(student.serializeBinary())
    
            //Row 2
            student.setId(2)
            student.setName('st2')
            student.setAge(15)
            
            serializedRows.push(student.serializeBinary())
    
            var protoRows = {
                serializedRows
            }
            var proto_data = {
                writerSchema: {protoDescriptor},
                rows: protoRows
            }
    
            // Construct request
            request = {
              writeStream,
              protoRows: proto_data
            };
            
            // Insert rows
            const stream = await storageClient.appendRows();
            
            stream.on('data', response => {
              console.log(response);
            });
            stream.on('error', err => {
              throw err;
            });
            stream.on('end', async () => {
              /* API call completed */
              try {
                var response = await storageClient.finalizeWriteStream({name: writeStream})
    
                response = await storageClient.batchCommitWriteStreams({parent,writeStreams: [writeStream]})
              }
              catch(err) {
                  console.log(err)
              }
            });
            stream.write(request);
            stream.end();
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    
    }
    
    run();
```

Make sure your environment variables are set correctly to point to the file containing google cloud credentials.

Change project and dataset values accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Rayees thanks for the example! I don't feel bad for not being able to figure it out earlier :). I've captured some API feedback in the original issue since comments here aren't the right place: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage/issues/222